# How are voting percentages calculated?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

A few days ago, I noticed that I'm close to earning the Electorate badge; I just have to increase my percentage of votes on questions from 19% to 25%.  So I started making a conscious effort to vote more on questions.  Several days later... it's still reporting 19%, even though I've cast more votes than 1% of my total.  So how does this get calculated?

Comment: "992 question / 4,000 answer". Hm to get [Electorate](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/electorate), these 4,000 should be less than 75% of your total votes, meaning you need 1,334 total votes on questions. You need to vote up or down 342 more questions, this will take at least 9 days (40 votes on questions a day) - assuming you won't vote answers

Comment: As an aside, questions with a score of -4 or less will kick them off the front page. So if you're looking for extra reasons to vote on questions, keep this in mind.

Comment: ... and speedy delete votes on the questions such that they get deleted will refund up / down votes cast on the same day. There are also [questions where a single down vote will delete it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0..0+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+score%3A1..1+locked%3Ano), also giving you refunded up / down votes. There are ways to speed up the rate of question vote casting by helping the moderation process along. On Stack Overflow, there were days I cast in excess of 60 votes / day.

Answer (score 6):

You have nearly 5000 votes cast ([stats](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/935/mason-wheeler?tab=topactivity)).  As of this writing, you have 992 question votes and 4000 answer votes. This is about 19% (992 / 4992 = 0.1987...).  To get to 25%, you will need to have a `question votes / (question votes + answer votes)` be 25%.

Assuming you hold answer votes constant:

```
X / (X + 4000) = 0.25
             X = (0.25) * (X + 4000)
             X = (0.25 * X) + 1000
       .75 * X = 1000
             X = 1333
```

So, you will need about 340 more votes on questions.